cnnhistory=model.fit(x_traincnn, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=500, validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test)) None values not supported error
I am creating a program which will predict the emotion from a voice data. But I am getting this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items' for the line
cnnhistory=model.fit(x_traincnn, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=500, validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test))
I have double checked x_traincnn, x_test, y_traincnn, y_test, none of them contain any None or NaN value. How to solve this problem?
I am using the RAVDESS Emotional speech audio dataset from Kaggle and the code is basically from This Repository
I just modified a little bit.
Also I am giving my code.
import numpy as np
import librosa
import glob
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

int2emotion = {
    "01": "neutral",
    "02": "calm",
    "03": "happy",
    "04": "sad",
    "05": "angry",
    "06": "fearful",
    "07": "disgust",
    "08": "surprised"
}

AVAILABLE_EMOTIONS = {"angry", "sad", "neutral", "happy"}


def extract_feature(file_name, **kwargs):
    mfcc = kwargs.get("mfcc")
    chroma = kwargs.get("chroma")
    mel = kwargs.get("mel")
    contrast = kwargs.get("contrast")
    tonnetz = kwargs.get("tonnetz")
    with soundfile.SoundFile(file_name) as sound_file:
        X = sound_file.read(dtype="float32")
        sample_rate = sound_file.samplerate
        if chroma or contrast:
            stft = np.abs(librosa.stft(X))
        result = np.array([])
        if mfcc:
            mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
            result = np.hstack((result, mfccs))
        if chroma:
            chroma = np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=sample_rate).T, axis=0)
            result = np.hstack((result, chroma))
        if mel:
            mel = np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=X, sr=sample_rate).T, axis=0)
            result = np.hstack((result, mel))
        if contrast:
            contrast = np.mean(librosa.feature.spectral_contrast(S=stft, sr=sample_rate).T, axis=0)
            result = np.hstack((result, contrast))
        if tonnetz:
            tonnetz = np.mean(librosa.feature.tonnetz(y=librosa.effects.harmonic(X), sr=sample_rate).T, axis=0)
            result = np.hstack((result, tonnetz))
    return result


def load_data(test_size=0.2):
    X, y = [], []
    pathx = "D:\\Programming_related\\PROJECTS\\ALL_PROJECT\\voice-processing-with-ai\\Actors_1\\Actor_*\\*.wav"
    for file in glob.glob(pathx):
        try:
            basename = os.path.basename(file)
            print(f"Processing file: {basename}")
            emotion = int2emotion[basename.split("-")[2]]
            if emotion not in AVAILABLE_EMOTIONS:
                print(f"Skipping file: {basename} (emotion {emotion} not in AVAILABLE_EMOTIONS)")
                continue
            features = extract_feature(file, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True)
            X.append(features)
            l = {'happy': 0.0, 'sad': 1.0, 'neutral': 3.0, 'angry': 4.0}
            y.append(l[emotion])
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing file {file}: {e}")
            continue
    if len(X) == 0:
        raise ValueError("No data found. Please check the file paths and ensure the dataset is correctly placed.")
    return train_test_split(np.array(X), y, test_size=test_size, random_state=7)



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = load_data(test_size=0.25)

print("[+] Number of training samples:", X_train.shape[0])
print("[+] Number of testing samples:", X_test.shape[0])


import numpy as np
X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
y_train= np.asarray(y_train)
X_test=np.array(X_test)
y_test=np.array(y_test)


X_train.shape,y_train.shape,X_test.shape,y_test.shape


x_traincnn = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=2)
x_testcnn = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=2)


print("Shapes after expanding dimensions:")
print(f"x_traincnn shape: {x_traincnn.shape}")
print(f"x_testcnn shape: {x_testcnn.shape}")
x_traincnn.shape,x_testcnn.shape


import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same',input_shape=(180,1)))        #1
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8)))



model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same',))                           #2
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(8))                                                 #3
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
# opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.00005, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.00005, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)



model.summary()


model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])


cnnhistory=model.fit(x_traincnn, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=500, validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test))


loss, acc = model.evaluate(x_testcnn, y_test)
print("Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%".format(100*acc))



Here is the full error message:
Cell In[52], line 1
----> 1 cnnhistory=model.fit(x_traincnn, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=500, validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test))

File d:\Programming_related\PROJECTS\ALL_PROJECT\voice-processing-with-ai\.conda\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File d:\Programming_related\PROJECTS\ALL_PROJECT\voice-processing-with-ai\.conda\lib\site-packages\keras\src\trainers\trainer.py:923, in Trainer._pythonify_logs(self, logs)
    921 def _pythonify_logs(self, logs):
    922     result = {}
--> 923     for key, value in sorted(logs.items()):
    924         if isinstance(value, dict):
    925             result.update(self._pythonify_logs(value))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'```


Please [edit] the title to be a better summary of the problem. Code goes in your post, not your title.

any recommended title ??? i am really confused with it Sir.
